# Recursive Python function for Chess

Tags: python, generator, yield, chess

I'm trying to write a algorithm that finds the fastest way to checkmate by computing all possible games from the current position of the pieces (only Kings and rooks) and basing the next move on the shortest number of moves to checkmate or stalemate.

I'm having issues understanding how to use python generators to do this. *My question is this the correct use of generators and the yield keyword?*

heres my very brief psuedocode

```
  play(maxMoves, gameBoard):
      while not checkmate and gamemoves is less than maxmoves:

            if whitesturn:
                   legalmoves= all legal white moves
                    for x in legalmoves:
                        testBoard=deepcopy of board
                        testboard. makemove(x)
                        movesItTook=play_Gen(10,testBoard) 
                        if(movesItTook is less than previous best)...this is our new bestmove





  play_Gen(maxMoves, gameBoard):
      while gameboard is not checkmate and gamemoves is less than maxmoves:

            if whitesturn:
                   legalmoves= all legal white moves
                    for somemove in legalmoves:
                        testBoard=deepcopy of board
                        testboard. makemove(somemove)
            if(checkmate)
                yield gameBoard.turncount
```

Comment: http://simeonvisser.com/posts/python-3-using-yield-from-in-generators-part-1.html

Comment: Your code seems to be missing the `def` keyword.

Comment: I don't think you need a generator in this code. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you don't have a generator, how would generate the chess moves?